# How do you solve this small Boolean Algebra problem?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Boolean algebra:

`a + ~a.b`

This is as far as I got:

```
= a + ~a.b + a.~a
= a + ~a(b + a)
```

I know that the answer is `a + b` however I can't seem to prove it.

I would be very grateful if someone could show the steps to proving it.

Comment: Thanks for reorganizing the question, I'm not sure how to make the new lines actually appear

Comment: This problem would become very simple if you use `K-map` https://www.electrical4u.com/simplifying-boolean-expression-using-k-map/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this easily is:

```
= a + ~a.b
= a.(1+b) + ~a.b
= a + a.b + ~a.b
= a+ b.(a + ~a)
= a + b
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way to solve this is to break it down.

```
I prefer to use  & and | and !.

1.  A & (!A | B)

2.  (A & !A) | (A & B)   Distributive property

3.  0 | (A & B)          (A & !A) just like True and False can never be True

4.  A & B
```

You may also want to look at [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)